# Practical usage of Moment of inertia

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

A small confusion in understanding the practical application of moment of ineria. Why is most of the mass of the wheel concentrated on the rim? I know that it is to increase the moment of inertia, but what is the practical use of doing so?

Comment: Hint: Do you know the formula for the moment of inertia? What does that tell you about the problem?

Comment: I formula is I=mr^2 . but what is the use of large moment of inertia in vehicles ?

Comment: I have to apologize, I think I misunderstood your question. In bicycles the angular momentum of the wheels is used to stabilize the bike.  Look at the formula for the precession frequency of a gyroscope with torque: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession. The larger the moment of inertia, the slower the precession frequency. The rotating bike wheels will respond to the bike leaning to one side with a precession movement. The slower this movement, the easier for the driver to compensate. In addition, the spinning wheels will produce a torque that helps to keep the bike balanced.

Comment: @CuriousOne - That's highly non-trivial!

Comment: @New_new_newbie: It's much worse than you think. Klein and Sommerfeld wrote a four volume tome about the theory and application of gyroscopes at the beginning of the 20th century... and that's just a tiny fraction of the literature that was written about rotating bodies. There is nothing trivial about them.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Nope. I didn't mean to say gyroscopes were trivial or non-trivial, I meant the fact that precession enters this picture as in ''_The rotating bike wheels will respond to the bike leaning to one side with a precession movement. The slower this movement, the easier for the driver to compensate._'' THIS is non-trivial.

Comment: @New_new_newbie: We completely agree. It is non-trivial, even for relatively simple cases like a perfect gyroscope. Personally I find it very counter-intuitive that a gyroscope responds to a torque perpendicular to the axis of its rotation with a second torque perpendicular to both. It's hard to visualize (and believe), if you didn't have the chance to play with one of these for a while. The experiment will impart an intuitive feeling for what happens, after which some of the math becomes easier to motivate (at least for the mathematically challenged, like myself).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a deliberate design decision to concentrate the mass in a wheel at the rim. Indeed (for motorcycles at least) this is something to be avoided because it makes the wheels harder to turn and reduces the speed in corners.

There is a minimum mass the rim can be because it has to be strong enough to hold the tyre in place while the vehicle moves. Likewise there is a minimum mass the spokes can be because they have to be strong enough to hold the rim in place. It turns out it's easier to make the spokes light than to make the rim light, and that's why in a wheel most of the mass is in the rim.

So having most of the mass in the rim isn't the result of a deliberate decision to make the rim heavy, it's because it's easier to reduce the mass of the spokes than to reduce the mass of the rim.